# About Mesh cipher

Tags: cryptography, mesh

Could anyone help explain to me about mesh cryptography*? because I know it has the basic operation of IDEA still its pretty intimidating for me. Thanks community!

~John

Answer (score 0):

[Did you try google? The link from crypto wiki looked especially promising.](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHKZ_enUS431US431&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=MESH%20cipher%20explanation#pq=mesh%20cipher%20explanation&hl=en&authuser=0&cp=10&gs_id=35&xhr=t&q=MESH%20cipher&qe=TUVTSCBjaXBoZQ&qesig=8PnDhf3rxNlnnLUfW6Sh_g&pkc=AFgZ2tneaaIgWQt3fYadd7hUXUCkzBsZoqwB6aLoUNIkEpk19tWK_diqMCyH3TrSG90joPRfHLE2YJXCcsrGL5Cy2h0HH--s-Q&pf=p&sclient=psy&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enUS431US431&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=MESH%20ciphe&aq=0v&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=af2e63566b48d43&biw=1680&bih=965)